# sum without duplicates RDLC

Tags: sql, vb.net, reporting, rdlc

I have a report in RDLC. I try to sum up without duplicates. So how to sum ignoring duplicates??

```
№ sale         Date_Sales       Amount        Date_payment      Amount      
01-01         01/07/2013        1000          15/07/2013        500

01-01          01/07/2013       1000          18/07/2013        500

Total                          2000                             1000
```

and should be:

```
№ sale         Date_Sales       Amount       Date_payment      Amount       
01-01         01/07/2013         1000         15/07/2013        500

01-01          01/07/2013        1000        18/07/2013         500

Total                            1000                           1000
```

I hide duplicates in the second line but I can't avoid the sum of this duplicate fields. I need to see the sum of sales and the sum of payments in the same report.

Comment: from query or in rdlc?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL it would be

```
SELECT SUM(columnname) AS iSum FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT columnname FROM tablename) AS foo
```

Comment: Ok, but how implement it in the report? I can't use SELECT there.